# Is there any reason to repair items before they reach 0?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

In KoA it seems like the most cost-effective method for repairing items is to wait until their condition reaches 0 and then use repair kits. Are there any drawbacks to this? For example, is the item less effective as it gets more damaged? Is it possible for items to be damaged beyond repair?

Comment: I've got a feeling the awnser is no, but when my faeblades are nearly broken i've also got that they do less damage. Ofcourse if they are fully broken then your weapons only do like 1 damage a hit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience, the *cost-optimal* solution (when your Blacksmithing is high enough to repair your items with one kit) is to wait until they hit 0 durability remaining.

There is a warning when your items are *almost* broken, but I never really saw a significant difference in their performance at this stage.  I'd routinely finish the fight I was in the middle of if I got this warning.  The only difference I noticed is when they are completely broken.  Sometimes in the heat of battle I'd miss the damaged/broken warnings, and notice that my weapons were doing almost no damage.

Due to the fact that equipment effectiveness is almost completely negated when items are at 0 durability, I never spent enough time in that state to gauge if it is possible to lose them completely.  However, I seriously doubt this is possible.  I believe the only drawback to being at 0 durability is the item being nearly useless.

I qualified my answer as being "cost-optimal" because this has practical implications.  Once the durability of one piece of armor is critically low, it's likely that multiple pieces of equipment require repair.  In practice, I tended to repair everything below a certain threshold once one of my items broke - this way, I didn't have to go into and out of the menu as frequently.  Also, this kept me from situations where much of my armor failed at once, leaving me defenseless.  Money tended to be less valuable than my time  - either time spent paging through the menus or time spent loading if I lost due to equipment failure.

Comment: Even with only 1 point of blacksmithing, I never saw an item that couldn't be fully repaired with a single kit. I'm curious if you've had a different experience.

Comment: @Sterno What kinda items are you using? Even with 3 points in Blacksmithing i need to repair my fully broken epic items with like 50 durability atleast twice...

Comment: @Sterno, I didn't really start using kits until I had several points in blacksmithing, so I don't know how a point of blacksmithing correlates to durability gains from repair kits.  That said, most of my items were in the 15-30 range of max durability, and I don't think I encountered a situation where I couldn't repair with just one kit.

Comment: @Lyrion Maybe that's my problem then. Even by level 37 with awesome blue chakrams that did 180 damage, I don't think I had any items with with more than about 40 durability.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I've found that there is no difference in performance until I'm warned that my stuff is almost broken, at which point I switch to a backup weapon/armor until I get out of the dungeon I'm in.

However, I have found myself in a pattern of questing until my inventory is full, then warping to a safe zone (Didenhill Crafter's Boutique, usually), fixing my broken stuff, salvaging the bits I like, ditching the bits I don't and then evaluating my weapons, armor and potion needs. Then I hit the healer (if needed) on the way out and then I'm back on the road again.

It costs a bit more to keep you goodies at full marks but you just can't beat that peace of mind that your stuff won't give out mid-dungeon.

Comment: You can repair your equipment from the pause menu in the middle of a fight. Literally between hits. When the message comes up saying it's broken, just pause and fix it.